# how do I get ActionDescriptor from either ActionExecutingContext or AuthorizationContext?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inheritance

I'm writing a method that just uses the ActionDescriptor property but I can't figure out how to avoid repeating the body of the method so that it can take either an ActionExecutingContext or an AuthorizationContext.  Both of these types have an ActionDescriptor property, but they don't inherit it from a common type or interface that I can find.

Answer (score 1):

Refactor the code that consumes the `ActionDescriptor` into its own static method somewhere, then call that method from within your `OnActionExecuting()` or `OnAuthorization()`, passing in the `ActionDescriptor` object.

Comment: Yeah, I did that, but there is still a little repeated code there... would like to just eliminate it entirely.

Comment: What's the repeated code?  If the interesting logic consumes only the ActionDescriptor object, then it can be refactored into a single non-duplicated method that takes only that as a parameter.  You'd still need to call it from both OnActionExecuting() and OnAuthorization(), but that doesn't really count as duplicate code. :)

Comment: Yeah, it's not much... just the line that gets the ActionDescriptor... but it seems not quite ideal